# Extract tar achives into separate folders

Tags: bash, tar

I have a folder containing many tar archives

- archive1.tar
- archive2.tar
- ...

I'd like to write a bash script which extracts their innard files to separate folders:

- archive1
- - file1-1
- - file1-2
- - ...
- archive2
- - file2-1
- - file2-2
- - ...
- ...

My best shot so far is this script:

```
for file in ./*tar; do tar -xf $file -C .; done
```

The problem with it is that it just dumps all the files into the . folder.

I'm really puzzled about how can I specify the destination folder after -C, or there is another way to make this work.

Comment: `-C $(basename "$file" .tar)` ?

Comment: `-C .` doesn't do anything, since that's the default location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subdirectory named after the tarfile and use that instead of `.`

```
for file in *.tar; do
    dir=$(basename "$file" .tar)
    mkdir "$dir"
    tar -xf "$file" -C "$dir"
done
```

Comment: It worked! I had to create the directories you declared though by running this script, as tar was angry at their absence:
```for file in *.tar; do dir=$(basename "$file" .tar); mkdir $dir; done```

Comment: I meant to put that in the script and forgot